# Identify a story about genetically engineered Vampires

Tags: story-identification, vampire, genetic-engineering

I've been trying to track down details of a neat story I read years ago that told several tales about people living in an overpopulated Earth where Vampires and other mythological creatures were now real.

What I can remember ...

- The Earth was critically overpopulated
- A well resourced group decided the problem was a lack of human predators and set out to create a few new ones based on classic mythology, seeking to "thin the herd" by eliminating the weakest
- They released some kind of contageous vector (a virus?) that resulted in a very small proportion of fetuses being modified in-utero, though the effects didn't become evident until puberty
- They chose this approach because it would take effect on a global scale, and so they wouldn't themselves know who the predators were
- Several kinds of predator, including Vampires and Werewolves - but Vampires are the ones that stuck in my mind
- Vampires were long lived, incredibly strong and needed blood to survive - at puberty they lost the ability to make something found in blood, so they needed another source. They were pale (something to do with their blood problems?) but didn't otherwise have any problems with exposure to the Sun.

There were several stories, though I can't remember whether it was a book of short stories or several plot lines in one larger story. One of the story lines started with some kind of investigation into a series of gruesome murders that took place as the first of the "new-predators" reached puberty, and lead into the discovery of what had been done.

At the end of the book, everyone was adjusting to "the new normal", a world where vampires, werewolves and other creatures were real, rare but dangerous.

I read this either in late high school or while at university, so I'd peg the timeframe as between 1987 and 1993.

Comment: Hope you get an answer, because this sounds like an awesome read!

Comment: I keep checking back here, I am excited to read this if we can ever find it.

Comment: I hope this gets answered someday.

Comment: This sounds very similar to a book (possibly series?) that a former co-worker told me about a couple of years ago, but I don't recall the name of it.  Was it a book or a short story?  If it was a book, then I'm pretty sure I can get in touch with her still.

Comment: I remember multiple protagonists (a detective, a reporter, a teenage vampire, others) so it wasn't a single short story; it could have been one of a series - would be great if you'd contact your colleague.

Comment: I apologize, I just saw your comment and had completely forgotten about it.  I will email her today!

Comment: This isn't it (published 2006, hence a comment), but [Blindsight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindsight_(science_fiction_novel)) contained re-created Vampires - not as the main plotline, but one was a member of a starship's crew. (No Werewolves that I remember). In any case, it was an *excellent* story, highly recommended. The Vampires were well-designed, with a rationale that nicely explained why they went extinct in the first place.

Comment: If there is such a story as this, The screenwriter for Daybreakers, would have pulled a lot from the pages of it, because you state several of the problems that he focuses on it that moive, the inability to produce blood being the main over all problem. Ill do some research and see what i can come up with

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_(novel)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like part of the overall story arc from the [Infinity Project](https://infinityheroes.wordpress.com/) series by [Saje Williams](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/741203.Saje_Williams).

*Loki's Sin* - This is the first book which describes the creation and release of the viruses by Loki and the creation of the first vampires.

*Of Man and Monster* - Sequel and follow on from Loki's sin. Again about vampires and this time the first werewolf. The main story in this one follows a small town sheriff investigating murders in her town - the work of vampires and her son who is a vampire

The series continues with vampires and werewolves being integrated into society and the reason behind the virus' creation, that an alien race which hops universes and takes over the various earths.

1. *Loki's Sin*
2. *Of Man and Monster*
3. *Freak City*
4. *Lady of Blades*
5. *Sword and Shadow*
6. *Death of Heroes*
7. *Tales from the Magitech Lounge*

Comment: This has a lot of similarities - I'll have to get copies and read them. I'm not sure that the timeframe fits though - Loki's sin was published March 2011, whereas I'm remembering stuff from the early 1990's.

Comment: Loki's sin first published 2004-2005 (2011 was a later edition), but your right, it cant be the book or series your looking for if your remembering stuff from 90's

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps much, but Your initial description sounds a lot like an RPG I played a while ago called *Shadowrun*. Well... at least the explanation of how the other species came to spread around the world (shifty eyes).